# Moving a generic template with restrictions out of the class definition

Tags: c++, templates, typename

The following example compiles and shows the correct endresult. EDIT: in the sense that three lines are printed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct normal
{
    static void log(const char * out) { cout << out << endl; }
};

struct other
{
    static void log(const char * out) { cout << out << endl; }
};

//Implementation inside the class declaration
template<typename output = normal>
class LogUser_H
{
public:
    void print() { output::log("template"); }
};

//Move Implementation moved out of the class declaration
template<typename output = normal>
class LogUser_CPP
{
public:
    void print();
};

//Specialised definitions
void LogUser_CPP<struct normal>::print(void) { normal::log("normal specialisation"); }
void LogUser_CPP<struct other>::print(void) { other::log("other specialisation"); }

//Template definition ?
//void LogUser_CPP</*??*/output/*??*/>::print(void)
//{
//    output::log("template");
//}

int main()
{
    LogUser_H<> H;
    H.print();
    LogUser_CPP<> C1;
    C1.print();
    LogUser_CPP<other> C2;
    C2.print();
}
```

The class `LogUser_H` has a method that calls a function in a struct. `LogUser_CPP` is meant to do the same with the twist that I want to move the method definition out of the class definition and write it below. Doing so I no longer have a definition for `output` and I can not get to the function in structs that fulfil the output requirement. I can however provide specialized versions of struct and compile that way.

How can I delete the two specialized implementations `void LogUser_CPP<struct normal>::print(void)` and `void LogUser_CPP<struct other>::print(void)`? In want to replace them with a generic implementation looking something like the commented out implementation `void LogUser_CPP</*??*/output/*??*/>::print(void)`.

EDIT 1:
I tried the following:

```
//Specialised definitions
//void LogUser_CPP<struct normal>::print(void) { normal::log("normal specialisation"); }
//void LogUser_CPP<struct other>::print(void) { other::log("other specialisation"); }
template<>
void LogUser_CPP<>::print(void)
{
    output::log("template");
}
```

This will not compile.

EDIT 2: 
I tried the following:

```
//Specialised definitions
//void LogUser_CPP<struct normal>::print(void) { normal::log("normal specialisation"); }
//void LogUser_CPP<struct other>::print(void) { other::log("other specialisation"); }
template<typename output>
void LogUser_CPP<>::print(void)
{
    output::log("template");
}
```

This will not compile.
The error is `error C3211: 'LogUser_CPP<normal>::print' : explicit specialization is using partial specialization syntax, use template <> instead`
Could this be compiler specific? This computer has VS2013 Express on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
template <>
void LogUser_CPP<normal>::print(void) { normal::log("normal specialisation"); }

template <>
void LogUser_CPP<other>::print(void) { other::log("other specialisation"); }
```

or

```
template<typename output>
void LogUser_CPP<output>::print(void)
{
    output::log("template");
}
```

Comment: I tried something along these lines and edited the question. My point is to get rid of the specialised implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I tried it any my compiler does not like it. Is that compiler specific?

Comment: Sorry, I had an error there. I forgot to use `output` with `LogUser_CPP`.